# CodeIgniter image_lib resize error 500 on some pics

Tags: php, codeigniter

On some images I get the error 500 when resizing.  First I thought it was the file size ~4M; however, after further testing, it does work on larger pictures.  So there is something that exists causing the error.  Need some pointers on how to best trouble-shoot the root cause and determine best treatment.

Here is the code snippet:

```
$config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['quality'] = 40;
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = $fileString;
$this->image_lib->clear();
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

Comment: are all the images you are using the same format or varying? (jpg, png, etc). You will need more detailed information as to what you are doing and what you have tried to get help....

Comment: All the pictures are jpg.  If I take the resize out, the pictures do upload fine and can be displayed without any issue.  Is there a debug option for resize?

Comment: Have you got the answer yet? I got the same problem and have the image if you need to check.